Unable to display correct paging
I am trying to create a function that returns a string like
1 - 10, 11 - 20, 21 - 30
I have the function below working but just cant get the math right I'm using:
entries = 6
per_page = 2
I'm getting 1 - 2, 4 - 5, 5 - 6
function GetChartPages($week)
{
    global $smcFunc, $scripturl;

    $links = '';
    
         $weekquery = $smcFunc['db_query']('', '
            SELECT w.entries, w.wkend, c.per_page, c.chart_id, c.member_id
            FROM {db_prefix}personal_charts_weeks AS w
            INNER JOIN {db_prefix}personal_charts_names AS c ON (w.chart_id = c.chart_id)
            WHERE w.week_id = {int:this_week}',
                [
                    'this_week' => $week
                ]
            );
            
        $week_record = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($weekquery);
        $smcFunc['db_free_result']($weekquery);

        $totalPages = ceil($week_record['entries'] / $week_record['per_page']);

        
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {

        $links .= '<a href="'
                    .$scripturl
                    .'?action=music;area=mycharts;sa=chart;chr='
                    .$week_record['chart_id'].
                    ';wk='.$week_record['wkend'].
                    ';u='.$week_record['member_id'].'">' .
                    ($i == 1 ? $i . ' - ' .($week_record['per_page']) : ($week_record['per_page'] + $i) . ' - ' . ($i +  $totalPages)).'</a>, ';
        }
        
        return '<br>'. $links;
}

I have modified the code but just can't get it right

"I am trying to create a function that returns a string like" - At the risk of sounding pedantic, it appears you want to return HTML that includes links for pagination. Although the math should be the same, I think it is important to note, especially because it does not appear that you are using said pagination in the URL at all.

I was going to add that once the display was correct thanks

I will add something like ';page='.($week_record['per_page'] + $i).'  to the link once I can work the math out which is still eluding me :)

The math is $start = $page*10+1; $end = $page*10+10;, assuming page numbers start at 0. If page numbers start at 1, use ($page-1) in place of $page.

sorry, tried applying that but messed it up, ($i == 1 ? $i . ' - ' .($week_record['per_page']) : ($i * ($week_record['per_page'] + 1)) . ' - ' . ($i +  ($week_record['per_page']+$week_record['per_page']))).', ';

Although not (necessarily) wrong, I'm curious about the ; instead of & in the URL?

It's code for a smf forum, I keep it inline with all other code.

try this, hope this helps with your math:
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalPages; $i++) {
        $start = $i * $week_record['per_page'] + 1;
        $end = min(($i + 1) * $week_record['per_page'], $week_record['entries']);

        $links .= '<a href="'
                .$scripturl
                .'?action=music;area=mycharts;sa=chart;chr='
                .$week_record['chart_id'].
                ';wk='.$week_record['wkend'].
                ';u='.$week_record['member_id'].'">' .
                $start . ' - ' . $end . '</a>';

        if ($i < $totalPages - 1) {
            $links .= ', ';
        }
    }


Thanks seems to be working I'll have to study up on that as don't understand $end = min(($i + 1) * $week_record['per_page'], $week_record['entries']); with ref to using ,

@MickJaves we are using min here so that end does not exceed total number of entries, let say 15 items, per page 10 then:
$end = min(($i + 1) * $week_record['per_page'], $week_record['entries'])
for first iteration where $i = 0
min((0 + 1) * 10, 15) = min (10,15) so first page end is 10
1-10
second iteration where $i = 1
min((1 + 1) * 10, 15) = min (20,15) so second page end is 15
11-15
